# Convert ordinal to interval data with mirt package in R

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I have ordinal data from 2 questionnaires. One questionnaire has a scale of 1:7 and the other of 1:5. I would like to convert these data to interval using polytomous item response theory. I can calculate the thresholds and draw the plots, but don't understand how to use this data to convert my raw ordinal data into interval data.

```
df = data.frame("Q1" = sample(1:7, 100, replace = T), "Q2" = 
sample(1:5, 100, replace = T))

library(mirt)
model = mirt(data = df, model = 1, itemtype = "gpcm")
coef(model, IRTpars = T)
plot(model, type = "trace")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is factor scores, which are estimates of the latent variable on the interval scale computed from the model parameters and the input data. In `mirt`, the function is `fscores()`, which takes in an object that is the output to `mirt()` and produces a vector of values. These values are the scale scores that collapse your data into an interval value.

Comment: The OP stated his manifest variables are ordinal in which case graded partial credit seems appropriate. He wants to estimate the underlying latent variables which would be interval in Stevens' typology.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood. By "convert these data to interval" I assumed he meant his raw data, not create an interval variable as factor scores from a model.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Say each questionnaire had 10 questions, is there a way to calculate the factor scores for each question as opposed to the total score?